# MSAL Authenticated/Unauthenticated Template Components not working after calling HandleRedirectPromise

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal

I have a React app where I am using the msal libraries for authentication through Azure B2C, and I am using a login redirect flow. Until recently, I knew that the token was stored in session after login, and I was pulling it out based on the default, complex key. I recently learned that you can call msalInstance.HandleRedirectPromise().then(...) to actually get the token back after redirect and store it yourself. However, after adding the call, both the Authenticated and Unathenticated Template components stopped working - Nothing from either one is rendering.

I know this is the case because I have reduced a simple case:

```
<AuthenticatedTemplate>AA</AuthenticatedTemplate>
<UnauthenticatedTemplate>BB</UnauthenticatedTemplate>
```

I am calling HandleRedirectPromise in my App.tsx file on every render:

```
this.props.instance
  .handleRedirectPromise()
  .then((tokenResponse) => {
    if (tokenResponse !== null) {
      const idToken = tokenResponse.idToken;
      sessionStorage.setItem("idToken", idToken);
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

When I remove the handleRedirectPromise call, the correct template renders. Do I need to manually set the ActiveAccount to get the templates to work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is returning because handleRedirection is returning a null token response.

This is a known bug in [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2420).
You need to add the /home route to your AAD app registration. Comment your redirectUri in b2c configuration and set the navigationToLoginRequestUrl to true.